# Get current directory on server PHP

Tags: php

I have the following function used to get the server info:

```
function srv_name(){
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 80) {
    $port = ':'.$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
} else {
    $port = '';
}
$name = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
    $http = 'https://';
} else {
    $http = 'http://';
}
return $http.$name.$port;
}
```

I use this as follows:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo srv_name(); ?>/css/styles.css">
```

This works if the php file is in the root dir of the web server eg: mydomain.com/index.php
But it does not work if the file is in a sub directory eg: mydomain.com/mydir/index.php

What do I need to add to the function to get the sub directory?

Comment: No, that returns the full unix/windows path of the working directory

Answer (score 3):

You could add `dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])`:

```
// ...
return $http . $name . $port . dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

Comment: Ah that seems kinda right, only problem is it now appends 'index.php' to the end which can be removed using substr(). Thanx alot.

Comment: @Stuyvenstein `dirname()` should have taken care of that, actually, unless `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` has a trailing slash .. is that the case?

Comment: No it's not, didn't think about that... duh! :)

Answer (score 2):

If the template file and css directory is in the same directory i.e.

```
mydomain.com/templates/mytemplate/index.php --> template
mydomain.com/templates/mytemplate/css/styles.css --> stylesheet in css direcory
```

then use

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

Comment: You're right but there was a reason I didn't do it that way and I can't seem to remember why, gotta spend a few minutes figuring it out...

Comment: Ahh, the reason is that the site's template is in a bunch of subdirs (mydomain.com/templates/mytemplate/template.php) and it's included in the root index.php (mydomain.com/index.php) so using `href="./css/styles.css"` in mydomain.com/templates/mytemplate/template.php will return mydomain.com/css/styles.css instead of mydomain.com/templates/mytemplate/css/styles.css

Comment: @Stuyvenstein will the css folder be in the same folder as the template? eg template in mydomain.com/templates/mytemplate/index.php and css in mydomain.com/templates/mytemplate/css/styles.css

Answer (score 0):

I'm using something like the code below to retrieve the path for a file that later we use as an output for an email message class in php.

```
                 //To this folder I'm uploading in another module

$folder='uploads/';


        //get the server address.. it's a vpn accessible ip in our case 
        $dev_baseurl= 'http://192.168.xxx.xyz';
```

//Function that worked for me in this case *(if there is an even better way feel free to add comments)

```
                    function check_address($current_dir,$https_check)
                    {
//$https_check, user defined var for
$conflen=strlen($current_dir);
//im using this and don't ask me why :P
$conflen1=0;

$B=substr(__FILE__,0,strrpos(__FILE__,'/'));
$A=substr($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], strrpos($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
$C=substr($B,strlen($A));

$posconf=strlen($C)-$conflen1-1;
$D=substr($C,1,$posconf);

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) $https_check=1;

switch($https_check)
{
case 0:
            $host='http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/' .$D.'';
break;

case 1:
            $host='https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/'.$D.'';
break;
}
//output the address
return $host;


 }
```

Trying to get a path to the remote hosted file

```
$dev2_url=check_address('/',1);

$dev2_url="{$dev2_url}";

/* That should be the output we are looking for 
   $dev_url="{$dev_baseurl}".str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))."/{$folder}";
*/
```

... some other logic in my php

```
     //$body is a message string that we are sending with a class call as a parameter later
    foreach( $_POST['attachments'] as $a => $avalue)
{
    if (is_file($avalue))
     {  

      $mime_type[$a] = substr(strrchr($avalue, '.'), 1);


    $handle=fopen($avalue, 'rb');
                                      $bs_name=basename($avalue);
                                      $filesize=filesize($avalue);
                                      $f_contents=fread($handle, $filesize);
                                      fclose($handle);
```

//get_mime_type2 checks for the filetype from a file, not relevant for this example, but it does for the output though                          if(isset($mime_type[$a]))$mime_type[$a] = get_mime_type2($mime_type[$a]);

```
                        $body.= '<li><ul><li>Filename:&nbsp;' . $bs_name .$eol;
                        $body.= '<li>FileType:&nbsp;'.$mime_type[$a].$eol;

                                            //In this line I use the calculated path to pass it as an output to an HTML based version of an email
                                            $body.= "<li>Path:&nbsp;<a href=\"{$dev2_url}/{$avalue}\" title=\"Open w/ browser {FileName: $bs_name} | Size: {$filesize}\" target=\"_parent\">"  .$avalue . "</a><li>Approx.File-Size:{$filesize} bytes</ul>";


                                    }
    }  
$body.='</ul>';
```

So note at this line:
...

```
$body.= "<li>Path:&nbsp;<a href=\"{$dev2_url}/{$avalue}\" title=\"Open w/ browser {FileName: $bs_name} | Size: {$filesize}\" target=\"_parent\">"  .$avalue . "</a><li>Approx.File-Size:{$filesize} bytes</ul>";
```

.. $dev2_url is being used to find the path to the file, and we append the filename and that should take care of it. I am aware that there should be a more elegant way to accomplish what the op needs, but without a real case scenario of what it could be used for I can only share my own implementation.

That gives me a convenient output to use.. IE:

```
//http://192.168.xx.xyZ is actually a real IP address

http://192.168.xx.xyZ/ProjectX/protos/jquery-menu2/includes/uploads/t_1.txt
```

for the output of each file that is attached to the email message